# JSF immediate="true" for cancel button doesn't work

Tags: jsf-2

I have a two tab page, one tab is the record list, click on the record will switch to the Edit tab, and there's Save and Cancel buttons in the Edit tab.

Now, I click on the record #1, do some edit, and click the Cancel button. Certainly I don't want to validate the form because it's canceled, so I set `immediate="true"` on the Cancel button. Now the edit tab is closed, back to the record list. Then, I click on another record #2, the problem occurred: In the edit tab, it's still the previous content of record #1, rather then record #2. I've checked the variables in debug view, the back bean for the edit form was ACTUALLY filled with record #2.

I.e., something broken after an immediate command.

(Everything had been well before I have added the validation and immediate="true".)

```
class FormBean {

    Record activeRecord;
    ...

    public void clickOnList() {
        activeRecord = loadRecord(clickIndex);
    }

    public void cancelForm() {
        activeRecord = null;
    }

}
```

page.xhtml:

```
<h:form id="main">
  ...
  <p:tab title="Edit" rendered="#{formBean.activeRecord != null}">
    ...
    <p:commandButton value="Cancel"
        actionListener="#{formBean.cancelForm}"
        update="main" async="true" immediate="true" />
  </p:tab>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `immediate="true"` doesn't work nicely with ajax requests on the same view. It boils down to that the submitted-but-not-validated values are still there in the input components. Without ajax, a normal synchronous request/response of a subsequent form submit would silently "solve" this. But with ajax, this does not happen. The submitted values of the previous ajax request are still there in the input components. When [`UIInput#getSubmittedValue()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#getSubmittedValue%28%29) doesn't return `null`, it will be displayed instead, irrespective of the (changed) model value.

Basically, when you want to stick to ajax for a cancel button, you need to **exclude** the inputs from being processed instead of relying on the `immediate="true"` (which is actually kind of a hack). In standard JSF `<f:ajax>` terms, you could do this with `execute="@this"` (which is actually the default) on the button instead of `execute="@form"`. The PrimeFaces buttons defaults to `@form`, so you need to change this:

```
<p:commandButton value="Cancel"
    actionListener="#{formBean.cancelForm}"
    update="main" async="true" process="@this" />
```